# Writing logs to files using Serilog is not working

Tags: asp.net, logging, serilog

I have an ASP .NET based application that uses Serilog for logging and I want to test it by writing my logs to files. I am using Serilog and Serilog.Sinks.File
So far, the code looks like this:

```
_perfLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.File("C:\\Users\\andav\\Desktop\\NewTest\\logger\\perf.txt")
                .CreateLogger();

_perfLogger.Write(LogEventLevel.Information, "{@LogDetail}", infoToLog);
```

But all my files are empty or are not created and I am not getting any errors.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn`t know that .Net is not allowed to write in any other folder except App_Data. This was the problem and I managed to fix it.

Comment: How did you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to if you add read/write permission for IIS_IUSRS on the directory.

I usually put the log directory in the same directory as my IIS app and do the following:

You need local admin permissions:

1. Right-click on the directory that you want to log file in
2. Choose properties
3. Go to Security tab
4. Click Edit
5. Click Add
6. Type IIS_IUSRS
7. Click on Check Names

If it cannot find it then click on locations

- Click on your computer name and click ok
- Now click on check names and it should resolve.

...

8. Click OK
9. Give the Modify Permission
10. Click OK

Logging "should" work

If it is a directory outside of inetpub, I am not sure but worth a try.

-Gina

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try.